# Puzzling behaviour of async

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11

This might be some weird Linux quirk, but I'm observing very strange behavior.

The following code should compare a synchronized version of summing numbers with an async version. The thing is that I'm seeing a performance increase (it's not caching, it happens even when I split the code into two separate programs), while still observing the program as single-threaded (only one core is used).

`strace` does show some thread activity, but monitoring tools like `top` clones still show only one used core.

Second problem I'm observing is that if I increase the spawn ratio, the memory usage just explodes. What is the memory overhead of a thread? With 5000 threads I get ~10GB memory usage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
using namespace std;


long long sum2(const vector<int>& v, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    const size_t boundary = 5*1000*1000;

    if (to-from <= boundary)
    {
        long long rsum = 0;
        for (;from < to; from++)
        {
            rsum += v[from];
        }
        return rsum;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t mid = from + (to-from)/2;
        auto s2 = async(launch::async,sum2,cref(v),mid,to);

        long long rsum = sum2(v,from,mid);
        rsum += s2.get();
        return rsum;
    }
}

long long sum2(const vector<int>& v)
{
    return sum2(v,0,v.size());
}

long long sum(const vector<int>& v)
{
    long long rsum = 0;
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        rsum += i;
    }

    return rsum;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t vsize = 100*1000*1000;

    vector<int> x;
    x.reserve(vsize);

    mt19937 rng;
    rng.seed(chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now()));

    uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist(0,10);

    for (auto i = 0; i < vsize; i++)
    {
        x.push_back(dist(rng));
    }

    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long long suma = sum(x);
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Sum is " << suma << endl;
    cout << "Duration " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() << " nanoseconds." << endl;

    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    suma = sum2(x);
    end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Async sum is " << suma << endl;
    cout << "Async duration " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() << " nanoseconds." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 10GB virtual or real? The virtual memory usage can easily explode, but the real memory usage shouldn't be that high.

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah, virtual is like 50GB :-D

Comment: On 64-bit operating systems, virtual memory isn't scarce. So there's no point in trying to use less of it or tracking how much of it is used. (At least, not until you're in the TB rage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you observe one core being used because the overlap between threads doing work simultaneously is too short to be noticeable. Summing 5mln values from a continuous area of memory should be very fast on modern hardware, so by the time parent finishes summing, child may have barely started and parent may be spending most or all of the time waiting for the result from the child. Have you tried to increase work unit to see if the overlap becomes noticeable?

Regarding increased performance: even if there is 0 overlap between threads because of too small work unit, multithreaded version can still benefit from additional L1 cache memory. For such a test, memory will likely be a bottleneck and sequential version will use only one L1 cache while multithreaded version will use as many as there are cores.

Comment: Have you tried running the code? This doesn't actually look like a problem with this. Too many threads would be a problem, but even reducing it to four (on my quad) doesn't actually make it perform much better. I even rewrote the code to schedule block optimally in advance.

Comment: But look at these numbers: http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-numbers-that-every-computer-engineer-should-know-according-to-Jeff-Dean for this kind of problem, the program will spent most of the time reading input from the main memory, which is sequential (DRAM does not allow concurrent access).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the times that are being printed? On my machine, the serial time is under 1s at -O2, whilst the parallel sum time is several times faster. It's therefore entirely possible that the CPU usage is not enough for long enough for things like "top" to register, since they typically only refresh once per second.

If you increase the number of threads by reducing the count-per-thread, then you effectively increase the overhead of the thread management. If you have 5000 threads active, then your task will take 5000* min-thread-stack-size in additional memory. On my machine that's 20Gb!

Why don't you try increasing the size of the source container? If you make the parallel section take long enough, you'll see the corresponding parallel CPU usage. However, be prepared: summing integers is **fast**, and the time taken generating the random numbers can take an order of magnitude or two longer than the time to add the numbers together.